# How to remove blank spaces between xAxis labels?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to draw graphs on the fly.

As you see the below picture, there are a lot of blank spaces between years.

How can I shrink it?

I want to use the spaces to expand width of each column item.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your groupPadding value very close to zero (or zero).

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            groupPadding: 0.01
        }
    },
```

Since you didn't post your code, I'll show another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ztYLv/)

Comment: You're welcome. But remember, if you want to trim any unnecessary space it can't be done in Highcharts. For that, you need to use Highstocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the column width by using pointWidth and shrink the spaces between years using groupPadding.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            groupPadding: 0.01,
            pointWidth: 50
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mehesh Sapkai, it's good to apply the maximum pointWidth; however, it should be calculated again when users enlarge or shrink a graph or they change the size of a window.